# ¿Cómo importar txt a Excel por nombre?

Tags: excel, vb6, microsoft-office, vba

¿Podrían indicarme por favor una línea de código con vba en el cual yo pueda abrir todos los archivos txt de una carpeta para importarlos a excel pero que solo me importe aquellos que tienen determinado nombre?

Es decir, por ejemplo, yo tengo una carpeta de facturas donde unas facturas comienzan con AC, AM, AT, UP, CT y cosas así y por ejemplo solo quiero que me abra las que comienzan por AC, CT... Si me hago entender...

Gracias.

Tengo esto por ahora:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Origen
    'a = Range("AC", "AP", "AU", "AH", "AM", "")'

    On Error Resume Next

    Origen = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\"
    milibro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set navegador = CreateObject("shell.application")

    Carpeta = navegador.browseforfolder(0, "SELECCIONA CARPETA", 0, Origen).items.Item.Path
    ChDir Carpeta & "\"
    archi = Dir("*.txt")

    Do While archi <> ""
        Workbooks.OpenText archi, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=False
        otro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Workbooks(milibro).Sheets(1)
        Workbooks(otro).Close False
        archi = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

ya que seleccionas  tus archivos con un dir que te parece esta solución
puedes cargar los prefijos en un array

```
Dim prefix As Variant
        prefix = Array("AC", "AM", "AT", "UP", "CT")
```

luego iterar por ellos con el comodin * para buscar los archivos que inician con ese prefijo:

```
archi = Dir(prefix(i) & "*.txt")
```

en tu ejemplo completo seria mas o menos asi:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Origen
    'a = Range("AC", "AP", "AU", "AH", "AM", "")'

    On Error Resume Next

    Origen = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio\"
    milibro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set navegador = CreateObject("shell.application")

    Carpeta = navegador.browseforfolder(0, "SELECCIONA CARPETA", 0, Origen).items.Item.Path
    ChDir Carpeta & "\"

    Dim prefix As Variant
    prefix = Array("AC", "AM", "AT", "UP", "CT")
    For i = 0 To 4
        archi = Dir(prefix(i) & "*.txt")
        Do While archi <> ""
           Workbooks.OpenText archi, origin:=xlWindows, startrow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Local:=False
           otro = ActiveWorkbook.Name
           ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Workbooks(milibro).Sheets(1)
           Workbooks(otro).Close False
           archi = Dir()
        Loop
    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!